# How to perform Ctrl+Del in Vim while in insert mode?

Tags: vim, command, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know how to delete the word in front of the cursor while in insert mode in Vim? Most systems use `Ctrl+Del` to do this.

I know to delete the word behind the cursor in Vim is `Ctrl+w` while in insert mode, but I don't know how to delete forward.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/153372/is-there-a-way-to-forward-delete-in-insert-mode-in-vim

Comment: @jmargolisvt the link's solution only deletes one character of a word at a time, I am looking to delete the entire word with one keyboard command. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.vimrc` (for VIM or GVIM):

```
imap <C-D> X<Esc>lbce
;   1      2  3  4 5   ; just a comment for the further description
```

(In GVIM, `<C-Del>` also works.)

#### Description

1. Set the following binding on `Ctrl+D` in the insert mode.
2. Add a dummy letter to deal with words that initially contain only one character.
3. Leave the insert mode. (The cursor is on the added letter now.)
4. Move to the beginning of the current word.
5. Remove characters from the current position to the next end-of-word (i.e., from the first character of the current word to its last character). Then enter the insert mode again.

#### Behavior

- If the cursor was on a character of a word or immediately after the last character of a word (but not at the end of the current line), then this word will be removed.
- Otherwise, if there's a word to the left (on the same line), then it will be removed (without any blank characters).
- Otherwise (when there's no next word) the behavior is undefined. (Feel free to update the answer to cover these cases too.)

If a word is removed, then the cursor will be at the same position as the first character of the word was.

Comment: For some reason, when I map it to '<C-Del>`, but when I map it with `<C-a>` it works, do you know why this may be the case?

Comment: @YoursTruly I used `gvim`, so I tested the binding there. In `vim` under `xterm(1)` and `terminator(1)`, `<C-Del>` doesn't work indeed, despite that `Ctrl+Delete` is not listed as a binding in the configuration/docs of `terminator` (and `Ctrl+Delete` is not [listed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key#Table_of_examples) as a standard key combination on Unix). According to `:help :map-special-keys` and `man termcap`, something like `imap <t_^kD>` (but not exactly this) might work.

Comment: Fails for single-character words at the beginning of a line, in which case it will delete the following word, since `esc` will not pull the cursor back one position to the left, meaning `e` will move to the end of the next word (even if it's on the next line). Starting by moving the cursor to the right one step with `l` may fix this, as you won't be able to move beyond the EOL, and `esc` will move the cursor back again...

Comment: @Jangari Thanks for the observation. I've updated the answer based on your suggestion. But notice (regarding "you won't be able to move beyond the EOL") that if a command (like `l`) fails, then further commands of the binding won't be executed, which leaves some undefined behavior in the current solution. Personally, I am not interested in this functionality (I use `Ctrl+Backspace` sometimes in non-VIM editors but didn't even know about `Ctrl+Delete` before reading this question), so edits for further findings are welcome.

Comment: can you give us, please, the exact example just for `control+backspace` with deletetion of previous word

Comment: @alexzander I use `Ctrl-W` for that. (It works in the terminal too.)

Comment: yea, i found about that

Comment: if someone wants to map `ctrl+backspace` to delete a word in insert mode, try this: `noremap! <C-BS> <C-w> noremap! <C-h> <C-w>`

Answer (score 5):

**Use a single normal mode command, whilst in insert mode.**

To do this, whilst in insert mode, type

```
Ctrl+o
```

This tells vim to accept exactly 1 command as if it were normal mode. Then press

```
dw
```

to delete a word.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add below to your `.vimrc`

```
inoremap <C-Del> <C-o>dw
```

Comment: Explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473771/2192488

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is not exactly correct, right? It does delete backwards but not forward

In nvim this works:
`imap <C-Del> X<Esc>ce`